# Text in hover element not centering when changing font size

Tags: html, css

So i'm trying to have a div with text appear on a parent div when a mouse hovers the parent, all was going well and good until I encountered a problem where the text ("VISIT") was no longer centering when the font size is changed to be larger.

```css
.project-box {
   width: 1000px;
   background-color: white;
   height: 350px;
   margin: auto;
   box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px #737373;
}
.project-image {
   width: 400px;
   height: 260px;
   margin-left: 30px;
   background-color: #f1f1f0;
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   cursor: pointer;
}
.slidein-content {
   display: none;
   background-color: #ff9933;
   z-index: 1;
   width: 400px;
   height: 50px;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   text-align: center;
}

.project-image:hover .slidein-content {
   display: block;
}
.visit {
   font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif, Arial;
   color: white;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
   font-size: 2em;
```

```html
<div class="project-box">
    <div class="project-image">
        <div class="slidein-content">
            <p class="visit">VISIT</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the text "VISIT" is aligned properly horizontally, but not vertically. Anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a `<span>` element instead of a `<p>` element.  So modify your code to this:

```
<div class="project-box">
        <div class="project-image">
            <div class="slidein-content">
                <span class="visit">VISIT</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

That should help center it or at least get you in the right direction.  I tested this on jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v87Lqb6g/5/).  You may need to play around with the margin or padding a bit, but the problem you're having is because of the `<p>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Set a `line-height=0` on `.visit`

```css
.project-box {
   width: 1000px;
   background-color: white;
   height: 350px;
   margin: auto;
   box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px #737373;
}
.project-image {
   width: 400px;
   height: 260px;
   margin-left: 30px;
   background-color: #f1f1f0;
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   cursor: pointer;
}
.slidein-content {
   display: none;
   background-color: #ff9933;
   z-index: 1;
   width: 400px;
   height: 50px;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   text-align: center;
}

.project-image:hover .slidein-content {
   display: block;
   bottom:0;
 
}
.visit {
   font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif, Arial;
   color: white;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
   font-size: 2em;
   line-height:0;
```

```html
<div class="project-box">
            <div class="project-image">
                <div class="slidein-content">
                    <p class="visit">VISIT</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `top:50%;` and `transform: translateY(-50%);` to `.slidein-content`, erase the bottom:0 from it and add a`margin: 0` to `.visit` (I don't know from where, but it has a 32px top- and bottom-margin, which you have to reset to 0 that way.)

```css
.project-box {
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 350px;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 0px #737373;
}

.project-image {
  width: 400px;
  height: 260px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  background-color: #f1f1f0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slidein-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: #ff9933;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.project-image:hover .slidein-content {
  display: block;
}

.visit {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif, Arial;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-box">
  <div class="project-image">
    <div class="slidein-content">
      <p class="visit">VISIT</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```